# Comparisons of more than two lists in R

Tags: r, list, comparison

For my problem, I have 4 lists, each containing 10,000 elements. Let the lists be a, b, c, d. I can calculate Probablity(a<b) by just performing mean operation `mean(a<b)`. If I understand correctly, it compares each of the 10,000 elements in a and b in order and tells me for how many elements a<b holds (with the number being divided by total elements).

Now, I want to compute Probablity(a<b<c<d). I want r to compare 10,000 elements in order and tell me for how many elements does (a<b<c<d) hold. However, I'm unable to do it using the mean function since it doesn't accept more than one `<` sign. How can I use the mean function here? I'm an absolute beginner in r, but logically, I feel this should be straightforward rather than looping over everything and having a count variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
a <- runif(10000)
b <- runif(10000)
c <- runif(10000)
d <- runif(10000)
mean(a<b & b<c & c<d)
#> [1] 0.0425
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked as expected. I wonder why we just cant compare the 4 lists directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use logical operators, which are `&` (and) and `|` (or). These two are the parallel versions. An example:

```r
set.seed(7*11*13)  
n <- 100
a <- sample(1:1000, 100)
b <- sample(1:1000, 100)
c <- sample(1:1000, 100)
d <- sample(1:1000, 100)

mean( (a<b)&(b<c)&(c<d) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Rfast::coldiffs`.

```
mean(rowSums(Rfast::coldiffs(matrix(c(A, B, C, D), length(A), 4)) > 0) == 3)
#> [1] 0.0397
```

Or multiplication

```
mean((A<B)*(B<C)*(C<D))
```

For whatever reason, multiplying/adding logical tends to be faster than `&`/`|` in possibly every case I've encountered:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  coldiffs = mean(rowSums(Rfast::coldiffs(matrix(c(A, B, C, D), length(A), 4)) > 0) == 3),
  logical = mean(A<B & B<C & C<D),
  multiplication = mean((A<B)*(B<C)*(C<D)),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>            expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#>        coldiffs 253.701 384.6515 454.6581 402.551 429.6010 6795.401   100
#>         logical 131.201 160.5505 200.4389 166.051 173.1515 3510.901   100
#>  multiplication 100.601 122.5010 126.3041 126.001 132.2010  241.400   100
```

Data

```
A <- runif(1e4)
B <- runif(1e4)
C <- runif(1e4)
D <- runif(1e4)
```